# How do I handle overtime at work?

Tags: new-job, india

I am a newbie (8 months experience) in a coding related, service based startup company in India. Most of the time, I am forced to work overtime, during weekends, and during holidays. Neither my supervisor, manager, nor colleagues help me in this regard. I really enjoy my work, but I don't like to sacrifice my free time.

How do I handle it?

Comment: Please specify a country/state/location. The answers you're going to receive are going to be different based on where you are located.

Comment: Who forces you to do overtime?

Comment: And what do they do to force it?

Comment: And how is not being fired and being paid for your job (even if overtime is unpaid) "waste". Most people will complain that they need their free time etc., but "waste" is not a word I would entertain in this context. Also, what is the jurisdiction? Because in most jurisdictions there is a SERIOUS limit to overtime and overtime + weekends + holidays sounds like labor laws are ignored pretty significantly.

Comment: Welcome new user.  is this programming related ?   and, what country please?

Comment: Please edit your question and update it with the info being asked by others. I'd like to know if you have ever said no to such a request? What do you think will happen if you say,  *"Sorry, I can't work weekends - I have plans to spend it with my friends and family and I really need the break. I'll start work on what you asked the first thing on Moday."* If you are not sure, say it to them the next time you are asked to work overtime and tell us their response.

Comment: @Helena My project lead or my colleague (who has 3 yr exp). It's just that due to a load of work, I cannot complete it on time during office work. I get appraisal from my manager , but overtime (always unpaid) is something I cannot accept

Comment: And I have edited my answer based on questions put up by other people

Answer (score 9):

> I really enjoy my work, but I dont like to sacrifice/waste my free time.
>
> How do I handle it?

Find a job that doesn't require overtime. That likely means avoiding startups.

Comment: I feel this kind of answer isn't really helpful. With the world economy being what it is, not everybody can find and switch jobs easily. Especially an inexperienced person. Moreover, running away isn't always the apt solution. S/he is asking for inter-personal tips here on how to first try to resolve this issue before considering that "last option" (of quitting and finding another job).

Comment: @sfxedit > While maybe not terribly helpful, still it seems valid. When working in an environment where overtime is considered the norm, getting things to change is just going to be a waste of time and efforts. And not playing by the "rules" will probably just get you fired, so in the end you'll be looking for a new job anyway. Probably better to do it from your own initiative while you still have an income. I don't see it as running away, but moving forward.

Comment: @LaurentS.: _"My supervisor, manager, nor colleagues help me in this regard."_ implies that there is something to address here, so it's not just a matter of it being a norm or inevitable fact of life at this company. Also, I really disagree on principle with the core "you _might_ not be able to change it, so don't even bother trying" attitude. By that same logic, you could argue that OP _might_ not find a better job and thus shouldn't bother trying, leaving no option on the table. Quite the reverse: if leaving is already on the table, might as well _try_ talking to the company first.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: That might very well be the case, but it's (IMO) just not an argument for not engaging an employer you're already working for in favor of just blindly leaving without seeing if a working solution can be found for both parties. It's easy to recommend finding another job when it's just some online advice that doesn't affect the giver of that advice when they're not the person having to do all the leg work and take all the risk (e.g. if the company finds out and no other offer has yet been made).

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: The comments mention OP getting conflicting information (manager is okay with it, project lead is not). This again proves that it's not unavoidable (because otherwise the manager wouldn't consider agreeing to it), it's a matter of a genital measuring contest between two other people. Could you leave over that kind of thing, or advise people that they _could_ leave over that? Sure thing. _Should_ you leave over that, or advise people that they _should_ leave over that? **Resoundingy no**.

Answer (score 8):

Other than changing job and finding a larger company with fixed hours, here are some questions you should address first.

Are you really being forced? - Always remember that you can hand in your notice at any time. It's easy to forget this and feel trapped.

- Has your employer said you need to do overtime, or are you choosing to do it?

I say this because I know many people in start-ups that feel "forced" to work overtime. They do it and then complain about being overworked, but no one actually asked them to do it.

- What happens if you don't work the over time?

Are they going to fire you, or will the project be delayed... if you don't do it, does it really matter?

- Which country, and what does you contract say about overtime?

Do some research on employment law, it's likely there are maximum hours and laws on how/if an employer can require you to do overtime.

Comment: +1 for the question, "Are you really being forced?"  Startups have a culture, and it is easy to pick up on the cultural queues.  You have probably never been asked to work more hours, you just feel peer pressure to do so.  The answer is "don't have anything to do, so you should go home"  If you get ahead of your work (by working smarter, not by working more hours), you won't have anything to actively do.  Look into unit testing to save all of that manual verification time, and think of how to work faster (and then stop when the day is over, rest will help you work fast too)

Comment: Yes. I am forced. I travel almost 60 km a day (back and forth) and since my company does not have travel allowance, I ask them to leave 1 hr early. My manager (who is second in hierarcy) says that it's okay as long as I complete my work, but my Project Lead and other colleagues frown on that. ANd since I answer to my project lead, he asks me to stay for long

Comment: Also, due to insane workload, I cannot complete the work during office hours. So , I have to work overtime

Comment: You say you ask to leave early - it's not really overtime if you have to work your contractual hours. How many hours are in your contract, and does anyone complain if you leave after working those?

Comment: @Skumar - Sounds like you are asking to leave an hour early instead of working 8 hours then leaving.  You living 60 km away from your job isn't a company concern. Now if the company culture is to finish whatever you are working on 30 minutes before you are suppose to leave that would be considered OT (under the assumption that it takes 1 hour to finish it)

Comment: "You're not really being forced" is a lame excuse. If a company didn't want their employees working overtime they would say so and take steps to ensure that.

Comment: @Donald The country's regulations are overtime needs to be paid. And, the salary that I get is way (too much) below the salary that I use to afford a house nearby. Trust me, I dont complain about the money often. And talking about working for 8 hours, yes, **I work for 8 hours**. But the company (specifically the project lead) asks me to stay for another hour or even more, or work from home during weekends or holidays because he has told his clients that the work shall be done no matter what.

Comment: And more over, what I earn is way below average than what is the minimum wage. I am struck here mostly because of the pandemic. Since, there could be others facing the same issue, I was looking for ways to overcome mine

Comment: So get paid the OT otherwise don’t work it.

Answer (score -1):

As Joe says, find a job that doesn't require overtime. It may even be the company that you are working for. Once you decided for yourself that you are willing to leave this company and work somewhere else, and once you have found that there are other jobs around, lots of pressure is gone from you and you are in a much better position.

You can for example demand that you should be paid for your overtime. In most places, the company must pay you for overtime. An exception is the USA where you can be "exempted" and have to do unpaid overtime *if required by the business*. However, a business not hiring enough people to do all the work means it is not *required by the business*. You will likely see how suddenly overtime isn't required anymore if it isn't free for the company. Alternatively, you will see how overtime becomes much more acceptable if it puts money in your pocket.

OR you can tell them that your overtime means you are constantly overworked and not able to be as productive as you should be, and that you would do a much better job without the overtime. Which any decent manager would know anyway. If they *need* you to do overtime, then they are not really in a position to fire you, right? If they *threaten* to fire you, that's also a very strong argument. And knowing that you can get another job means you can make all these arguments with confidence.

Comment: This answer shows a serious misunderstanding of what it means to be an exempt worker.